# How many lines of code differs between two commits or two branches?

Tags: git

I want to know how many lines of code I changed between two different commits. My purpose is to understand  how many lines of code I've written today but my abstract idea is to understand how many lines of code I've write from a moment to another one. Can someone help me for this stuff?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`--shortstat` is what you want:

```
git diff --shortstat commit1 commit2
```

You could also use it like:

```
git diff --shortstat "@{1 day ago}"
```

Answer (score 4):

Like many git commands `git diff --shortstat` doesn't just work with commits, but also with branch names, tags, etc. So if you're on a `feature/foo` branch and want to compare to `develop` run.

`git diff --shortstat develop`

If you want to know how many lines changed since the last version tag (e.g. `3.1`) run

`git diff --shortstat 3.1`

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, and in case multiple people commit to the same branch, use the `--author "<author name>"` to account only for your own commits.