# List files where number of lines changed in each file between two diffs is greater than x

Tags: git

I have a commit with a massive number of changes. Thousands of lines have been changed. However, in most files, the only change was a one line copyright notice at the top (the year changed). I'm trying to find files where this wasn't the only change. My approach was to find the files where more than one line has changed between the diffs for each file. For whatever reason, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916101/how-many-lines-of-code-differs-between-two-commits) approach hasn't worked for me. It just shows warnings about line endings. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
git log -10  --numstat | egrep ^[[:digit:]]+ | egrep -v ^1[[:space:]]+1[[:space:]]+
```

If only one line was changed then both first and second columns equals to 1. The second egrep filters them out.

-10 is just for testing purposes. You can just supply the commit id in the git log command.
If you are interested in a particular commit the command looks like this:

```
git log -1 --numstat e87bf0c | egrep ^[[:digit:]]+ | egrep -v ^1[[:space:]]+1[[:space:]]+
```

Comment: Thank you. I installed Cygwin and run this and it looks like it's working. I can't understand the output exactly. There are three columns of data. The first contains numbers that are usually 2 digits long but can be bigger, the second are usually zeroes and the third is the file name. Is it 1. num bytes changed, 2. num lines changes, 3. file in which changes occurred? Also, I'm being greedy here, but is it possible to only show .cpp files that have changed.

Comment: add `| grep cpp` in the end.